# SQL Syntax Sum and Count

Tags: mysql

I have a 1064 error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspond to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use neear `'*) as NB_FR, sum (*)) as MT_FR
>   FROM gc_mouvements where COOPX="477" or COOPX="4'` at line 4

Here is the code I used, I don't understand the origin of the error:

```
ALTER TABLE gc_modele_retrait ADD COLUMN 
    (Nb_frais_477 int(5),Nb_frais_481 int(5),Mt_frais_477 int(5),Mt_frais_481 int(5));

UPDATE gc_modele_retrait 
    SET Nb_frais_477=0, Nb_frais_481=0, Mt_frais_477=0, Mt_frais_481=0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gc_modele_retrait_frais;

CREATE TABLE gc_modele_retrait_frais
(PRIMARY KEY (COCO))
ENGINE=myisam
SELECT COCO, COOPX, COUNT(*) AS NB_FR, SUM(*) AS MT_OPE
FROM gc_mouvements WHERE COOPX="477" OR COOPX="481" GROUP BY COCO, COOPX;
```

Comment: I guess `SUM (*)` causes an error - what column are you trying to calculate sum for?

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to calculate the `Nb_frais_477` and `Nb_frais_481` column

Comment: So, something like `SUM (Nb_frais_477 + Nb_frais_481)` or even without `SUM` (just add these two columns)? - maybe I got it wrong, I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish...

Comment: Ok, the `SUM (Nb_frais_477 + Nb_frais_481)` works ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem :) Let me post this as an answer, so it can be accepted and more useful to someone with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with using `SUM (*)`, you have to pass numerical value or column containing numerical value to `SUM`. In your case you need:

```
SUM (Nb_frais_477 + Nb_frais_481)
```